# why is this java initialization giving error?

Tags: java

I am trying to initialise the array C in the loop, but it gives error :
C is array of class ipdata and I have declared it and trying to initialise it inside the loop.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class cluster_anlysis {
    class ipdata{


        float a,b;
        int cluster;

        ipdata()
        {
            a=0;
        }
    }
    public float modc(float a){
            if(a<0.0)
                a=-a;
            return a;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        cluster_anlysis obj=new cluster_anlysis();
    ipdata C[] = new ipdata[50];
    float mean1,mean2,mean3;
    int i,j,n1=0,n2=0,n3=0,flag=0;
    float ina=0.0f;
    float inb=0.0f;

    //BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    Scanner scan =new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("pls enter no of data: ");
    Integer no = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("\nnow enter the x and y values");
    for(i=0;i<no;i++)
    {
        ina=scan.nextFloat();
        inb=scan.nextFloat();
        System.out.println(ina);
        C[i]= new ipdata();          // this line is giving error

        C[i].a=ina;
        C[i].b=inb;
        C[i].cluster=0;
    }


    }

}
```

What could be the problem ?
it says :
No enclosing instance of type cluster_anlysis is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type cluster_anlysis (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of cluster_anlysis).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you create an *instance of inner class* from *static methods of your outer class* using the *outer class instance*.

```
c[i]= new cluster_anlysis().new ipdata();
```

as you have alread created cluster_anlysis instance in your first line of main method.

```
cluster_anlysis obj = new Cluster_anlysis();
```

you could simple do.

```
c[i]= obj.new ipdata();
```

read about [Inner classes in java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

but if you want to *create an inner class instance* from the *non-static methods of your outer class* you dont need the instance of your Outer Class .

```
 public class OuterClass {
       public void method(){
           InnerClass inner = new InnerClass();
       }
       class InnerClass{
         }
    }
```

and also follow class name convention as posted by @A.R.S and @JB Nizet in their solutions.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you're starting with Java. I would advise to avoid messing with inner classes for the moment. Define each Java class in its own file, and everything will be simpler.

Also learn about Java naming conventions:

- classes start with an upper-case letter, and are CamelCased: `ClusterAnalysis`, `IpData`. They should not contain underscores.
- variables start with a lower-case letter, and are camelCased: `c`. They should not contain underscores.

Once you are more comfortable with the basics, learn about inner classes and static inner classes in [the Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html). But inner classes should not be abused. The basic rule is to have one class per file.

Comment: +1 - The OP needs to get the indentation and embedded white-space right too.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best thing to do would be to declare `ipdata` as **`static`**; that would eliminate the error. There should be no need to instantiate `cluster_analysis` in order to instantiate `ipdata` in this case, and it makes sense that `ipdata` should in fact be `static`.

---

Oh, and by convention, you might want to consider using the names `IpData` and `ClusterAnalysis` instead - class names generally start with a capital letter and are "CamelCased", as another answer also pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

Use outer class Instance to call inner class constructor

like

```
c[i]=new cluster_analysis().new ipdata();
```